# How to read schema fields (especially xml type) from tridion using core service factory java?

Tags: core-service, schema, xml

I am able to read xml `name`, `description`, `details` whether it is mandatory or multivalue using core service factory java.

> I am not able to read xml type. There is no method called 'Gettype'.
>   Could anyone please tell me how to retrieve xml type?

Thanks in advance!

My code goes like this.

```
ICoreService oClient = CoreServiceFactory.getBasicHttpClient();
SchemaFieldsData schemaData = oClient.readSchemaFields(str, true, null); 
ArrayOfItemFieldDefinitionData design=schemaData.getFields(); 
List<ItemFieldDefinitionData> design_item = design.getItemFieldDefinitionData();
for(ItemFieldDefinitionData loopVariable : design_item)
    {         
     String xmlName=loopVariable.getName();               
     String description=loopVariable.getDescription();                
     String multiValue=(loopVariable.getMaxOccurs()==1) ? "No" : "Yes";               
     String mandatory=(loopVariable.getMinOccurs()==1) ? "Yes" : "No";     
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean how to determine the field type: it is reflected in the type of your `loopVariable` (which is a pretty lousy name for a variable, BTW :-)

Note that `ItemFieldDefinitionData` Is an abstract base class. The actual instances will be of a concrete subtype which reflects the field type.

Comment: Thanks for an idea. Yeah, ItemFieldDefinitionData is a root class. 
         
String xmlClass=loopVariable.getClass().getSimpleName();

From this, I am able to get sub class names like EmbeddedSchemaFieldDefinitionData,
MultimediaLinkFieldDefinitionData etc . which gives my answer.